# Problem with TortoiseSVN drag and drop classes to textarea in Firefox

Tags: firefox, drag-and-drop, textarea, tortoisesvn

When dragging php files from the TortoiseSVN commit window into an textarea the textarea receives the files multiple times.

When dragging 1 file, the textarea receives it one time.

When dragging 2 files, the textarea receives it two times.. and so on. 
Example image:
[image: Exmple]

This seems to appear only in Firefox. (My Version is: 72.0.2 (64-Bit))

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

None of the involved programs (Firefox, TortoiseSVN or Subversion itself) have the concept of "classes" but I can reproduce the issue if I drag some files from the commit dialogue. As workaround, I suggest you use the clipboard instead, which also offers a higher degree of customisation. Right click on the file list and select an appropriate item in the *Copy to clipboard* submenu:

[image]

Then just paste into Firefox the usual way: right click and *Paste*, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or whatever.

Comment: Sadly the files are copied (with strg + c) with relative path.They are full path when i drag / drop. I also dont have the option to copy with full path like you

Comment: @Zuyas I suspect you're better off reinstalling TortoiseSVN. There's clearly something corrupted.

Comment: this problem also appears at all of my friends using TortoiseSVN and Firefox